# Drag and Drop a Groupwise Email to C# Winform

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, groupwise

I have a need to be able to drag and drop a groupwise email to my winform application and am not having any luck at all.

I am able to get a filename as such but it is only a name, not a path.

Every time I call

```
e.Data.GetData("FileContents", true))

or

e.Data.GetData("FileContents", false)) 

or

e.Data.GetData("FileContents"))
```

I get null returned.

Also, the GetFormats returns something strange and a simple Google search returned nothing. One of the formats was `WPOF_DBOBJ_DRN`.

If anyone has some insight on this it would be greatly appreciated.

#### Update:

Just to add a few more details about this, there is also nothing on the clipboard from the drag and drop. Also took a look at the groupwise editor and word perfect isn't even installed on my pc and is most definatly not the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following links (I know, some of them are for Delphi, but you should get the idea):

[Drag and drop from an email file attachment in GroupWise to a .NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896197/drag-and-drop-from-an-email-file-attachment-in-groupwise-to-a-net-application)

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_21198933.html

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_23015275.html

Comment: Have already looked at those.

The first one doesn't apply because the email doesn't have attachments and I can't get any data following that sample.

The last one is the same as the first one except in delphi.

As for the second one, I can get Outlook messages across no problem using a very similar solution.
My problem is the Groupwise email data isn't brought over. I can get a memory stream from WPOF_DBOBJ_DRN call but writing that to a file results in an unreadble file. So, first I though it might be encoded etc, but the file size doesn't match if i do a save-as from groupwise...

Comment: Is there a way you can save the file using a COM object or something? I guess this would give you the option of reading the email contents from file. I searched Google for your WPOF_DBOBJ_DRN format too, but found nothing either. Are you 100% sure that this is the right format description? Maybe you can find more information on: http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/Develop_to_GroupWise

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a look at trying that. I've also tried to implement the IStorage interface into an IDataObject interface using unmanaged code and still aren't having any luck. (The Interface is also used to get Outlook messages that are dragged and dropped and works fine.)

That format is most definatly one of the formats i get back from calling e.Data.GetFormats();

I'll take a look at that link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WPOF_DBOBJ_DRN looks like WordPerfect Office Format - Database Object. I can't figure out what the DRN stands for though. See if you can open the unreadable file with Word, or WordPerfect if you have it. My guess is that the setup of GroupWise that you are using has WordPerfect as its editor.